# How to remove HTML comments in precompiled underscore templates using browserify

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, browserify, underscore.js-templating

I have some underscore.js templates, which I precompile using node-underscorify from npm.

```
browserify: {
app: {
    files: {
        'dist/js/app.js': ['app/main.js']
    },
    options: {
        transform: ['node-underscorify'],
        debug: true,
        external: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'backbone.marionette']
    }
}
}
```

Problem : it does keep html comments.

There doesn't seem to be a comment removal option in the documentation.

I could add a step of html comment removal but I directly require the results in a JS file along with all my code, and I don't want to put my JS in an html minifier to remove HTML comments. It wouldn't work I guess. Or it would be weird anyway.

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/wiki/list-of-transforms ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your styles.css If you use underscore this will remove your code in comments.

```
.form-allowed-tags{
    display: none;
}
```